# Peculiar behavior of TrackballControls.target in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, controls, trackball

I am trying to create a simulation of 3D distribution of galaxies.

The galaxies are points.

[question1.htm](https://github.com/RiteshSingh/galaxies/blob/181fa84ac3cb5cfdc733ff87f383f6629ef9016a/question1.htm) uses [galaxydata1.txt](https://github.com/RiteshSingh/galaxies/blob/181fa84ac3cb5cfdc733ff87f383f6629ef9016a/galaxydata1.txt) to calculate and load the galaxy positions:

```
rawFile.open("GET", "galaxydata1.txt", false);

var parts = data[i].split("\t");

var D = parts[0];
var glon = parts[1]*3.1416/180;
var glat = parts[2]*3.1416/180;

var z = D*Math.sin(glat);
var xy = D*Math.cos(glat);
var x = xy*Math.cos(glon);
var y = xy*Math.sin(glon);

dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z ));
```

I want the simulation to work in resource-limited devices. So, I figured that I can **calculate the positions beforehand and save them in a file.**

I did this using [write.htm](https://github.com/RiteshSingh/galaxies/blob/181fa84ac3cb5cfdc733ff87f383f6629ef9016a/write.htm) to [create galaxydata2.txt](https://riteshsingh.github.io/galaxies/write.htm).

[question2.htm](https://github.com/RiteshSingh/galaxies/blob/181fa84ac3cb5cfdc733ff87f383f6629ef9016a/question2.htm) uses [galaxydata2.txt](https://github.com/RiteshSingh/galaxies/blob/181fa84ac3cb5cfdc733ff87f383f6629ef9016a/galaxydata2.txt) to load the galaxy positions:

```
var parts = data[i].split(" ");

rawFile.open("GET", "galaxydata2.txt", false);

dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( parts[0], parts[1], parts[2] ));
```

It can be verified that the transformation is accurate because **both [question1.htm](https://riteshsingh.github.io/galaxies/question1.htm) and [question2.htm](https://riteshsingh.github.io/galaxies/question2.htm) generate exactly the same models.**

Now, I have implemented a galaxy search function, which searches a galaxy by name and centers it using:

```
controls.target = dots.geometry.vertices[i];
```

You may **try it by searching for m31** (one of the names for the Andromeda galaxy).

Bewilderingly, while **the galaxy search function works in [question1.htm](https://riteshsingh.github.io/galaxies/question1.htm), it doesn't work in [question2.htm](https://riteshsingh.github.io/galaxies/question2.htm)!**

I have spent tens of hours since the last 2 days trying to find the cause, but **cannot get head or tail of it.**

Note that I have used **exactly the same code to calculate the positions in both the cases.**

Most probably, I am missing something which would be immediately clear to the experts here.

If / when possible, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dots.geometry.vertices in your search function have not been converted into floats.. they are all strings.

1: n {x: "-34.10470732858122", y: "95.77578953486031", z: "-66.52906941334713
"}
2: n {x: "-23.203470164906907", y: "64.44921156287786", z: "-43.97565350543055
"}
3: n {x: "-22.228259825915906", y: "57.0117730686664", z: "-31.448405312168955
"}

So that will not work.

You will need to do a .parseFloat on the data after you load it before stuffing it into the geometry.

Comment: Is there an **immense gratitude** button anywhere on the internet?

Comment: Michael, if you are on the threejs forum, could you link this answer there as well, for the benefit of the community there, and so that I can accept it there as well? https://discourse.threejs.org/t/peculiar-behavior-of-trackballcontrols-target-leaves-me-dumbfounded/

Comment: Dear Michael, Fortunately, this project culminated in a publication: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3668727 and https://academic.oup.com/astrogeo/article/61/4/4.42/5873800. I have tried to acknowledge your most kind help in the acknowledgements section of the paper: "Michael Schlacter on stackoverflow.com". Please do tell me if you would like me to modify it.

Comment: Hahah that's very kind of you, Ritesh! Thank you... and I'm glad I could help. :) Congrats on publishing!!